# Implementation of built-in function Fold

Tags: functions, memory, implementation-details

In the documentation for fold, it says

> Fold[f,x,list] gives the last element of FoldList[f,x,list].

But this is surely not the way it is implemented, right? In those cases where each step of the `Fold` returns a large object, it would be a huge waste of memory to actually store the whole list and then just pick the last element at the end.

How can I test this? Does `Trace` work as advertised, or does it skip printing intermediate steps sometimes?

Comment: Try executing `TracePrint[Fold[f, a, Range[4]]]`.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi: Sure, but I asked the question because in this case a piece of the internal implementation _does_ matter; if it were done in one way, I would run out of RAM, and if it were done in another, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's quite easy to show that `Fold` doesn't use the memory that would be required to store intermediate results.

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
big = Range[1*^7];
ByteCount[big]
MaxMemoryUsed[] //N
```

> 40000124
>
> 5.49458*10^**7**

```
Fold[# + 1 &, big, Range@100];
MaxMemoryUsed[] //N
```

> 1.34909*10^**8**

`FoldList` by comparison (with a much shorter `Range`):

```
FoldList[# + 1 &, big, Range@30];
MaxMemoryUsed[] //N
```

> 2.49489*10^**9**

Comment: That's great, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can implement `Fold` without having to create an intermediate list. The documentation probably mentions that just to make the relationship between `Fold` and `FoldList` clear. For example, consider this simple construction of a `Fold` operation:

```
myFold[func_, x_, list_List] := Module[{f},
    f[a_, l_List] /; Length@l >= 1 := f[f[a, First@l], Rest@l];
    f[a_, {}] := a;
    f[x, list] /. f -> func
]
```

Now try it:

```
myFold[f, a, {b, c, d}]
(* f[f[f[a, b], c], d] *)
```

This is exactly what `Fold` would return. This and J. M.'s hint on `TracePrint` should make the implementation clear.

Comment: This implementation is nice conceptually, but has a serious flaw of not being tail-recursive. But, due to its clever scheme of first generating the expression in full and then evaluating, you fool the system so that it only requests to change the `$IterationLimit` (you basically construct a full but unevaluated call stack at once). The recursion is of course still there however, and when I try, e.g., `Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity},
 myFold[Drop, Range[100000], ConstantArray[1, {100000}]]]`, this silently blows the stack and crashes the kernel on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for the implementation example R.M, but I was more looking for a test than an example.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks for the detailed analysis. My intent was solely to show that `Fold` can be implemented without needing to build an explicit list and take the last element. I didn't even consider the concerns you raised (as is usual...) :)

Comment: You are welcome :) I did not wish do diminish your code at all. But this is a first time I see such a "well-hidden" recursion, so I thought it would be useful to add a comment on its existence and dangers. Also, generally, I think that when we consider emulations of some built-in functions, it is always good to spell out all the differences. This both helps to understand the function in question better, and the limitations of the emulated version.